# Get list of new wiki pages using Confluence API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

My goal is to retrieve the number of the new pages created each month in Confluence. I want to use Confluence API, but [Get Content](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/#content-getContent) doesn't seem like it provides the type of customization that would allow for returning a list of new pages or the number of new pages "by creation date." Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Advanced Searching using CQL](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/advanced-searching-using-cql#AdvancedSearchingusingCQL-GREATERTHAN:), they even described your usecase :)

The keyword you need is the **created** parameter. So if you want to search for all content created within the last 4 weeks (*created > now("-4w")*), you can try the following query:

```
/rest/api/content/search?cql=created%20>%20now("-4w")
```

This should return something like this, where **size** is the value you've been looking for

```
{
"results": [{
 ...
}],
"start": 0,
"limit": 1000,
"size": 1,
"_links": {
  ...
}
}
```

You can check the accuracy by adding the *&expand=history* parameter and see the *createdDate* for each page.

Be careful with the limit of results (by default 25). You can prevent this by setting a limit yourself *&limit=1000*. If you use an expand parameter, there is a max limit for searching - kinda confusing...

This should be the query for your search to find max 1000 new pages created in the last 4 weeks:

```
/rest/api/content/search?cql=created%20>%20now("-4w")&limit=1000
```